# How to use very latest OpenCV version in ROS?

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the very latest version of OpenCV in ROS because I want to integrate a critical bugfix from OpenCV. From what I read OpenCV is integrated by some 'magic' mechanism. Is it simply enough to replace my diamondback vision_opencv stack by the latest one from SVN, or do I also have to specify which OpenCV version is magically included?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9899/how-to-use-very-latest-opencv-version-in-ros?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-05-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The make file in `vision_opencv/opencv2` seems to contain the URI and svn branch it checks out. You could probably do what you are saying by changing that URI, though I'm guessing and can't confirm that this would work.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-05-06**:
True indeed, that's good advice. It's not recommended to mess around with any packaged installation. The steps remain the same, though.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-06**:
You should avoid changing the files included in the debs (the files that are in /opt/ros ) as they will likely be overwritten in the next update to that .deb package. You should instead overlay the vision_opencv stack and make your changes to this local overlay.

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-05-06**:
Yes. I backported latest OpenCV rev 5024 from trunk to aptitude ROS diamondback installation. Applied the following changes (1) SVN_URL="https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv", (2) SVN_REVISION="-r5024", (3) disabling out-dated patch "# SVN_PATCH = pythontest.patch". (4) Removed ROS_NOBUILD.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-05-05**:
This will work as long as you are building everything dependent on it from source.